# addAll method issues of collection interface

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is to perform two methods of collection interface with array-list i.e, I've created a simple menu.

Firstly I went with case 1 so the array-list 'arr' adds "ABC" in it and then I went for case 2, it seems like I'm  getting the wrong answer. for case 2, arr is null.

Answer I want for case 2: `[ABC,7,AB,34]`

Answer I'm getting: `[7,AB,34]`

```
import java.util.*;

    class ArrayList
    {
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
      Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
      int ch=0;
      do
      {
      System.out.println("Press 1,add.");
      System.out.println("Press 2,addAll.");
      System.out.println("Enter your choice?");
      Integer choice = inp.nextInt();
      ArrayList <String>arr = new ArrayList<String>();
      switch(choice)
      {
      case 1: 
      arr.add("ABC");
     System.out.println("Enter the elements in an arraylist:");
     int i=0;
      while(i<2)
      {
              String obj=inp.next();
              arr.add(obj);
            i++;        
      }
      System.out.println("The elements are:" +arr);
      break;

      case 2:
      ArrayList <String>arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
      arr.add("7");
      arr1.add("AB");
      arr1.add("34");
      arr.addAll(arr1);
      System.out.println("The elements are:" +arr);
      break;
      } 
      System.out.printf("Press 0 to continue?");
      ch=inp.nextInt();
      }while(ch==0);
     }
    }
```

Comment: For case2, "ABC" was never added in list arr. Its there only for case 1.

Comment: But it should exist in the memory. Before going for case 2 I went for case 1 so 'arr' array-list must hold "ABC". @BandiKishore

Comment: it won't be available in memory because you're clearing out the `arr` list and creating a new object. `ArrayList <String>arr = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Please tell me what to do if  I want to store 50+ more data in 'arr' by using a menu? @BandiKishore

Comment: Declare the variable `arr` (`ArrayList <String>arr = new ArrayList<String>();`)outside the do while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add arr.add("ABC");outside of case1 so that is it visible to case2.

```
import java.util.*;

class NewTestC
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
  int ch=0;
  do
  {
  System.out.println("Press 1,add.");
  System.out.println("Press 2,addAll.");
  System.out.println("Enter your choice?");
  Integer choice = inp.nextInt();
  ArrayList <String>arr = new ArrayList<String>();
  arr.add("ABC");
  switch(choice)
  {

  case 1: 
 System.out.println("Enter the elements in an arraylist:");
 int i=0;
  while(i<2)
  {
          String obj=inp.next();
          arr.add(obj);
        i++;        
  }
  System.out.println("The elements are:" +arr);
  break;

  case 2:
  ArrayList <String>arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
  arr.add("7");
  arr1.add("AB");
  arr1.add("34");
  arr.addAll(arr1);
  System.out.println("The elements are:" +arr);
  break;
  } 
  System.out.printf("Press 0 to continue?");
  ch=inp.nextInt();
  }while(ch==0);
 }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to store 50+ more data in 'arr' by just pressing 1? Suggest what am I suppose to do?